# How to input min/max values and have Excel generate cells for each number in the range

Tags: excel, range

I have 2 cells A2 and A3, I will input a min value and max value respectively in each cell. Say 100 in A2 and 200 in A3.

I would like Excel to populate cells with values within that range. So Column B would have cells 1-101 filled in with 100,101,103,104,105....200.

Is there any easy way to do this or should I just stick to putting 100 in B1 and dragging it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you first cell:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)-1+$A$2<=$A$3,ROW(1:1)-1+$A$2,"")
```

Then drag/copy the cells down far enough to cover any combination you will have.  You can fill the whole column if you want.

[image]

---

Microsoft is working on their Dynamic Arrays, Once released, a simple formula in the first cell of:

```
=SEQUENCE(A3-A2+1,,A2)
```

Will autmatically fill down the sequence without the need of dragging the formula down.

Comment: Thank you so much this was perfect!